# How does Raft guarantee that a leader can always be elected?

Tags: replication, distributed-computing, distributed, consensus, raft

The [Raft paper](https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf) says:

> Raft uses the voting process to prevent a candidate from winning an
> election unless its log contains all committed entries. A candidate
> must contact a majority of the cluster in order to be elected, which
> means that every committed entry must be present in at least one of
> those servers. If the candidate’s log is at least as up-to-date as any
> other log in that majority, then it will hold all the committed
> entries. The RequestVote RPC implements this restriction: the RPC
> includes information about the candidate’s log, and the voter denies
> its vote if its own log is more up-to-date than that of the candidate

How does it guarantee, however, that there will always *even be* an electable leader (i.e. one that's as up-to-date as a majority of cluster)?

For example, let's say we have a cluster of three servers A, B, C with A as the leader. First log entry is stored in A and B, second log entry is stored in A and C. Then A crashes, and B and C try to elect a leader. But at this point there is no majority (i.e. 2 out of 3) servers that have both first and second entries. So it seems like leader election can't ever happen (unless A restarts, but Raft's supposed to be resilient to a failure of 1 out of 3 servers..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper defines a "Log Matching Property" that is relevant to this scenario:

> • [..]
> • If two entries in different logs have the same index
> and term, then the logs are identical in all preceding
> entries.

Since A and C both contain the same second entry, C must also contain the first entry. This is ensured because:

> The second property is guaranteed by a simple consistency check performed by AppendEntries. When sending an AppendEntries RPC, the leader includes the index
> and term of the entry in its log that immediately precedes
> the new entries. If the follower does not find an entry in
> its log with the same index and term, then it refuses the
> new entries.

Until C has the entry that B has, it will reject further appends. So at some point in your scenario, C must have received that entry to finally accept the newer entry from A.

Therefore, C is the most up to date between B and C. (It would reject a leadership vote from B.)